# how to get counts for different contacts_status types in different periods as different columns in the same resulting dataframe?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

Hi i have segmented customers into different 'contacts_status' as well as their 'contacts_status
_in_previous_period'. There are 3 different categories 'active customers', 'inactive customers' and 'prospects'. The code that i have written has already done the segmentation.

What i want to do however is to total number of each type of 'contacts_status' in the current period as well as the previous period. For example, if contacts_status shows 'active customer' then i want to have 2 fields, the first titled 'contacts' that counts the total number of active customers in the CURRENT period and the second titled 'contacts_last_year' that counts the total number of active customers in the PREVIOUS PERIOD.

[This is what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLUah.png)

And this is the code that segments the customers into the various categories, would really appreciate some help on this:

```
#the next db is meant to segment the customers into different subtypes(eg. existing, new, prospect)
segmentation as (
  select t.*,
  #lets get the contact status of the customer in the CURRENT PERIOD
  case
      when trans_in_period = 0  and trans_before_period >= 1 then 'inactive customers'

      when (trans_in_period >= 1 and trans_before_period >= 1) 
      or (trans_in_period >= 1 and trans_before_period = 0) then 'active customers'

      when trans_in_period = 0 and trans_before_period = 0 then 'prospects'
  
  end as contacts_status,
  
  #Now lets get the contact status of the customer in the PREVIOUS PERIOD. This is so we can calculate the number of 
  #each type of contact in the previous year
  case
      when trans_previous_period = 0 and trans_before_previous_period >= 1 then 'inactive customers'

      when  (trans_previous_period >= 1 and trans_before_previous_period >= 1) 
      or (trans_previous_period >= 1 and trans_before_previous_period = 0) then 'active customers'

      when trans_previous_period = 0 and trans_before_previous_period = 0 then 'prospects'

  end as contacts_status_in_previous_period,

  case
     when opt_in_status = 'Y' THEN 'Yes'
     when opt_in_status = 'N' or opt_in_status is null THEN 'No'
  end as contactable,

  case
      when is_loyal = 'Y' THEN 'member'
      when is_loyal = 'N' THEN 'non-member'
      else 'N/A'

  end as member_status,

  case
     when first_buy_date >= from_date and first_buy_date <= to_date then 'new customer'
     when trans_in_period >= 1 and trans_before_period >= 1 then 'existing customer'
     else 'N/A'

  end as customer_type,

  case
      when trans_in_period = 1 and (first_buy_date >= from_date and first_buy_date <= to_date) then 'one time'
      when trans_in_period >= 2 and (first_buy_date >= from_date and first_buy_date <= to_date) then 'new repeat'
      when trans_in_period >= 1 and trans_previous_period >= 1 then 'retained'
      when trans_in_period >= 1 and trans_previous_r24_period >= 1 then 'winback'
      else 'N/A'
  
  end as customer_subtype,

  case
      when onlinetransinperiod >= 1 and offlinetransinperiod = 0 then 'online only'
      when onlinetransinperiod = 0 and offlinetransinperiod >= 1 then 'offline only'
      when onlinetransinperiod >= 1 and offlinetransinperiod >= 1 then 'omni'
      else 'N/A'
  end as purchase_channel,

  
  case
      when age >= 18 and age <= 24 then '18-24'
      when age > 24 and age <= 34 then '25-34'
      when age > 34 and age <= 44 then '35-44'
      when age > 44 and age <= 54 then '45-54'
      when age >= 55 then '55+'
      else 'unidentified'
  end as age_bracket,

  case
      when trans_in_period >= 2 then 'yes'
      when trans_in_period < 2 then 'no'
      else 'N/A'
  end as repeat_customer,

  case
      when sex = 'F' then 'female'
      when sex = 'M' then 'male'
      else 'unidentified'
  end as gender
  from trans t
  where age >= 16 and age < 81
),
```

I originally tried doing 2 different dataframes titled df1 and df2 to calculate the number of each contacts status type in their respective time periods and then join them together. However, not some contacts status types are showing null for contacts and contacts_last_year. Moreover, it takes up too much memory